# Are there Guarded Commands in Python / What are they?

Tags: python, command

Are there any [guarded commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guarded_Command_Language) in Python? And what are they?
I've searched every where, but i can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

The only preprocessor directive I was able to fine was the `__debug__` statement as explained by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482014/how-would-you-do-the-equivalent-of-preprocessor-directives-in-python).

It compiles to `True` when running python without any optimizations (no `-O` flag) and can optimize certain if statements as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524570/how-do-you-implement-ifdef-in-python).