# How should a Python file be written such that it can be both a module and a script with command line options and pipe capabilities?

Tags: python, import, module, stream, pipe

I'm considering how a Python file could be made to be an importable module as well as a script that is capable of accepting command line options and arguments as well as pipe data. How should this be done?

My attempt seems to work, but I want to know if my approach is how such a thing *should* be done (if such a thing should be done). Could there be complexities (such as when importing it) that I have not considered?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
usage:
    program [options]

options:
    --version        display version and exit
    --datamode       engage data mode
    --data=FILENAME  input data file [default: data.txt]
"""

import docopt
import sys

def main(options):

    print("main")

    datamode            = options["--datamode"]
    filename_input_data = options["--data"]

    if datamode:
        print("engage data mode")
        process_data(filename_input_data)

    if not sys.stdin.isatty():
        print("accepting pipe data")
        input_stream = sys.stdin
        input_stream_list = [line for line in input_stream]
        print("input stream: {data}".format(data = input_stream_list))

def process_data(filename):

    print("process data of file {filename}".format(filename = filename))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = docopt.docopt(__doc__)
    if options["--version"]:
        print(version)
        exit()
    main(options)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**That's it, you're good**.

Nothing matters`[1]` except the `if __name__ == '__main__'`, [as noted elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) (emphasis mine):

> A module’s `__name__` is set equal to `'__main__'` when read from standard input, a script, or from an interactive prompt. A module can discover whether or not it is running in the main scope by checking its own `__name__`, which allows a common idiom for conditionally executing code in a module when it is run as a script or with python -m **but not when it is imported**

I also like how python 2's [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__main__.html) poetically phrase it

> It is this environment in which the idiomatic “conditional script” stanza causes a script to run:

That guard guarantees that the code underneath it will only be accepted if it is the main function being called; put all your argument-grabbing code there. If there is no other top-level code except class/function declarations, it will be safe to import.

---

**Other complications**?

Yes:

1. Multiprocessing (a new interpreter is started and things are re-imported). `if __name__ == '__main__'` [covers that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222534/python-multiprocessing-on-windows-if-name-main)
2. If you're used to C coding, you might be thinking you can protect your imports with `ifdef`'s and the like. [There's some analogous hacks in python, but it's not what you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524570/how-do-you-implement-ifdef-in-python).

---

I like having a `main` method like C and Java - when's that coming out? [Never.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0299/)

---

But I'm paranoid! [What if someone changes my main function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375403/how-does-one-monkey-patch-a-function-in-python). Stop being friends with that person. As long as you're the user, I assume this isn't an issue.

---

I mentioned the `-m` flag. That sounds great, what's that?! [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610001/what-is-the-m-switch-for-in-python) and [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/), but don't worry about it.

---

**Footnotes**:

`[1]` Well, the fact that you put your main code in a function is nice. Means things will [run slightly faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241523/why-does-python-code-run-faster-in-a-function)

Comment: Oh, thank you so much for such a clear and detailed answer! That was very helpful and covered a few ideas I had not considered.