# How to mimic C's #define functionality to optionally print debug output in Python?

Tags: python, c, debugging, preprocessor-directive

I have a huge python code with lots of print statements useful for debugging. I want to be able to enable or disable them in one go, without poring over the hundreds of `printf`'s and commenting them each time.

In C, a `#define` can be used to comment out unneeded parts of the code using `#ifdef` like this-

```
#define debug
#ifdef debug
    printf("Debug on")
#endif
```

If I don't want to be in debug mode, I can simply comment #define debug and none of my `print` statements will compile.

How can this functionality be done in Python?

Comment: Since C macros are evaluated at compile time to simplify the runtime, and since Python does not have this separation, such a functionality doesn’t make much sense in Python. You can just use normal run-time checks to make branches (read: simple ifs).

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482014/how-would-you-do-the-equivalent-of-preprocessor-directives-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python has no direct equivalent of C's macros because it has no preprocessor and does not distinguish between compile-time and run-time like C does.

A simple solution however is to put your `print` lines inside an if-statement:

```
if False:
    print(...)
    print(...)
    print(...)
    ...
```

You can then just change the `False` to `True` to have them be executed.

---

Similarly, you could do:

```
DEBUG = False

if DEBUG:
    print(...)
    print(...)
    print(...)
    ...
```

and then change the `DEBUG` name to `True`.

---

A third (and probably the best) option would be to use Python's built-in [`__debug__` flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#__debug__):

```
if __debug__:
    print(...)
    print(...)
    print(...)
    ...
```

`__debug__` is a constant like `None` and is set to `True` if Python is launched without a `-O` option (it is in debug mode).  Otherwise, if a `-O` option is set (we are in optimized/production mode), `__debug__` will be set to `False` and the code using it will be entirely ignored by the interpreter so that there is no performance penalty.

Comment: Use `if __debug__`. This flag is set by the `-O` option and it actually *strips out* code when running in production (optimized) mode, so there is no performance penalty.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about `__debug__`.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the Python logging library:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the python standard library [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module. Here is an [easier-to-read tutorial on the logging module](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html).

You can set the debugging level for a given run of your code like so (see [this section](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html) for more info):

```
import logging
# if you want you can also set filename="logfile.txt" to write to file
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG) # there are other options like logging.INFO
x = 42.31415
# Run your program here....
logging.debug("x is now" + str(x))
```

So you could even pass the debug level at the command line if you so choose, say doing something like

```
--loggingLevel=DEBUG
```