# Is there a way to check the python interpreter version while the python code is getting converted to .pyc files?

Tags: python, bytecode, pyc

I am using `py_compile` to convert the python files(.py) to `.pyc` files.

```
py_compile.compile(py_src_file, doraise=True)
```

The python scripts contains code which have syntax both for python version 2.7 and 3.8 version.
The `py_compile` when using with python 3.8 version generates an error for corresponding 2.7 syntax. Is there a way to check the python version while compiling the code and compile corresponding instruction only.

For ex:

```
if python_version == 2.7:
   # py_compile should see 2.7 code
else:
   # py_compile should see 3.8 code
```

I got some help in this answer: [How would you do the equivalent of preprocessor directives in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482014/how-would-you-do-the-equivalent-of-preprocessor-directives-in-python), but don't know how to exactly use in my case.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Using a python preprocessor that has access to the version would be the way to go.  https://pypi.org/project/preprocessor/

Comment: If `py_compile` fails due to the mixture of version-specific syntaxes - then surely the files would fail in exactly the same way when actually imported?  I don't think you're trying to solve the right problem here.

Comment: @jasonharper.. I am thinking to use the conditional imports too based on the same above approach

Comment: Conditional imports of files that are individually in a single version's syntax would work - but then you'd have to run `py_compile` once with each version of Python, specifying only the files in its syntax.